# SQlite Error: Syntax error near 5 (better-sqlite3)

Tags: node.js, discord.js, better-sqlite3

```
client.on("message", message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
      const args2 = message.content.slice('test', ',', args).trim(args).split(' ', args);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === "tbal") {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
    const data = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get();
      message.channel.send(`You have ${data.bal}`)
  }
  if (command == "tgive") {
    //Get their current XP
    let userscore = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get()
    let pointsToAdd = parseInt(args2[1], [10]);
    if(!pointsToAdd) return message.reply("How much? You didn't tell me that!");
    //XP level update
    const valueadd = sql.prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ${args} (bal) VALUES (userscore + pointsToAdd);`)

    client.setScore.run(userscore)
    return message.channel.send(`${args} has received ${pointsToAdd}. New balance: ${data.bal}`);

}
});
```

There's the code, the error i'm getting is this: `` let userscore = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get() ``

`SqliteError: near "5": syntax error`

The near "5" is `args2`, to which I executed the command `eco tgive args1 5`, args1 being the name of the SQLite table.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you pass to the 'slice' function here:

```
const args2 = message.content.slice('test', ',', args).trim(args).split(' ', args);
```

do not make any sense.

Slice takes two parameters, a beginIndex and endIndex, both numbers. This is probably where the problem originates.

When you try to use the args param in

```
let userscore = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args}`).get()
```

it is likely in some unexpected state.

Here's docs on the slice method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> `SELECT bal FROM ${args}`
> ```

You need to use only the element you need from your `args` array as opposed to each argument. If `args1`  is the name of the table in the example command you provided, use this as your query, noting that `args[2]` is returning the third element in the array:

```js
`SELECT bal FROM ${args[2]}`
```

When converting the array into a string, its elements are joined together with `,` and results in the malformed syntax causing your error.

Comment: Adding that into the code, I get ``SqliteError: no such table: undefined``

Comment: @Kartingst That means that the expected argument was not provided by the user. Check that it exists first.